# What prevents HTML pages from taking advantage of progressive rendering?

Tags: html, rendering

I've notice that some pages begin to render almost immediately, while others sometime have to wait until many or all of the resources (javascript, image, css) have been downloaded. The worst case seems to be for a large page, on a slow connection or server.  One specific page I'm looking at comes out to almost 2 MB, with 30 different .js files, a dozen .css files, and 80 image.

I'm aware of the suggestions at http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html, but what would be preventing the browser from attempting to render the page until the last element has been downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

There are a handful of reasons why this may happen.  The most common that I see are large tables.

For example, Internet Explorer doesn't like to render a table until it is finished loading.

Each browser is a bit different though, in how they render things that are still downloading.

Comment: I'm interested in a list of items that might affect it.  In my case, there aren't any tables in the page, although there are 50 or so embedded scripts.

Comment: @chris, it would be helpful if you can give us a link and what browser you are seeing trouble in.  I can't give you a list, as *everything* affects it.

Comment: I've tried IE, FF and chrome, and none of them are doing progressive rendering.  Site is tourismnewbrunswick.ca

Comment: They are progressively rendering the page.  You have a few things hanging you up.  Whenever you put a script above other elements, the browser has to download that script before anything else can load.  You should really load your scripts at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Looking at your site, you have two main things holding you up.  The first is your skin.css file:  http://tourismnewbrunswick.ca/Portals/_default/Skins/TNB%202k9/skin.css  That thing is 378K... huge!  The browser waits for the whole thing to download before proceeding.  Next is http://newbrunswick-booknow.com/forms/tourismnewbrunswick_booking_form.js.php
  Again, 249K which has to download before proceeding.  Move that script to the bottom of the page, and do what you can to shrink both files.  They're way too big.

Comment: I should also note that your whole site weighs in at 2.2MB, which really is big.  On a typical modem connection, that is going to take 7 minutes to load, and they won't see anything for several minutes because your CSS and JS are so big.

Comment: Finally, you have two 404s:  http://tourismnewbrunswick.ca/Portals/_default/Skins/TNB%202k9/images/loading_animation.gif
   AND    http://tourismnewbrunswick.ca/css/tourismnewbrunswick_booking_form.css

Comment: If you use a tool such as Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), you can put it in "modem performance mode" and it will essentially slow down the transfer rate.  Even if you don't care about modem users, this slows it down enough so you can see what is happening, and the order of rendering and requests.

Comment: I've been using yslow and chrome developer tools to analyze the site. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is to not use tags about structure to affect layout. With the styles at the start of a page a rendering engine knows what it has to do to render a certain part of the page, but it always has to wait for a part to download to know how to render it properly.

With that in mind:

1. Tables should rearely (never?) be used for layout purposes.
2. Parts that should be reasonably rendered first (sidebars, toolbars, and anything that framews the page) should be featured at the top of the HTML document.

The huge JavaScript libraries in use today are different in that they only need to be loaded (and cached) once.

Comment: Tables should indeed never be used for layout purposes. It's not what it's made for. Tables are for tabular data, the same way a paragraph is for text and headers are for headers.